# Does stay put TM recognizes same languages as standard TM

Tags: computability, turing-machines

I am reading this text book and it says that stay put turing machine recognizes the same languages as regular turing machine by just adding transition functions (without adding any new states or symbols).
I am trying to figure that out.. But so far, no luck. I think the key here is "recognizes" rather than "decides"?
How do i prove this?
Thanks

Comment: Define stay put Turing machine.

Comment: @starflyer: A standard TM with head movements {L,R, S} where S is the head doesnt moves but rather just stays on the same position

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand your question, the standard TM only has moves {L, R} while the stay-put one has an additional move in S (stay). Obviously the stay-put TM will be at least as powerful as the standard TM (left to reader as an exercise). Then to say that it is the same, you just have to show that you can simulate a stay-put TM with a standard  TM. The key is obviously how to simulate a stay-put S move with the moves available to you (left as an exercise for the reader.)